# Cannot read property 'getLineAndCharacterOfPosition' of undefined

Tags: angular

I got stuck with this error, can someone help me out? 
I just upgraded to Angular2.4.3

```
$ ng serve                                                                                                                                                                              [19:46:01]
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
Hash: ed77e2590987da94e9d9                                                              
Time: 4165ms
chunk    {0} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.map (scripts) 1.42 MB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.map (styles) 203 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map (main) 576 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 234 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Cannot read property 'getLineAndCharacterOfPosition' of undefined

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/johntostring/Documents/web-workspace/ng2-qyweb/src/main.ts (3,40): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.)
/Users/johntostring/Documents/web-workspace/ng2-qyweb/src/main.ts (4,32): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/johntostring/Documents/web-workspace/ng2-qyweb/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:145:15)
    at /Users/johntostring/Documents/web-workspace/ng2-qyweb/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:172:17
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

---

main.ts
[image]

app.module.ts
[image]

Comment: I have executed `npm install`. All dependencies have been downloaded successfully

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been too long. I might have deleted the `node_modules` and tried  `npm install` again

Comment: Removing node_modules and re running `yarn install` did it for me.

Answer (score 21):

This happens when you modify `tsconfig.app.json` or `tsconfig.json` with invalid values.

Answer (score 2):

I triggered this slightly cryptic error when I accidentally forgot to return a value from a getter function in one of my components.

```
get gene() {
  // return this._gene;
}
```